# How to pause program on Solana?

Tags: anchor, rust, token, program

How can I pause program in Anchor on Solana like [pause](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/Pausable.sol) provided by Solidity?
I know programs on Solana is stateless, but I need to achieve this function.

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, since a Solana program is stateless, you can't really pause a program on Solana. You have a couple of options to achieve something similar:

- include some global "state" account on all instructions to your program. The global state account contains an `is_paused` field. During the program, if the field is set, it will abort any instruction. The `is_paused` field can only be set by some admin key
- upgrade the program to a no-op program